# Application or object defined error when using Set

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am getting an application or object defined error on the last line of the following vba code. Why?

```
Dim oRange As Range, a As Range, b As Range, c As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Wb1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook
Dim SearchString As String, FoundAt As String

On Error GoTo Whoa

Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Add
Set ws1 = Wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set c = ws1.Range(B4)
```

Comment: Hard to say, but the most logical reason would be if either [Sheet1] did not exist, or if it were *not* a worksheet (i.e., it is some other type of sheet, like a chart).

Answer (score 2):

Try using quotes with your string :)

```
Set c = ws1.Range("B4")
```

Comment: seems likely. would be good of OP clarified *which* `set` statement raised the error, but this one seems pretty obvious and the other two *should* work (assuming English language Excel).

Comment: he does say it's the last line :)

Answer (score 0):

`B4`, without quotation marks is treated as an undeclared variable, of type variant, with value 0/empty/nullstring. Since there is no range (really a `.Name`) with name `vbNullString` ("") this would raise a 1004 on the line:

`Set c = ws1.Range(B4)`

Qualify your string `B4` as a string:

`Set c = ws1.Range("B4")`